# Printf gives segmentation fault unless I do a "printf" first - C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, output, printf

I'm trying to import data from a file but I made a mistake (*after* this code below) so I was going to make some debugging, adding so the 15th line of this code:

```
fscanf(input, "%d %d", & numofusers, & numofmovies);
//-----users list allocation
for (int i = 0; i < numofusers; i++) {
    curruser -> usercode = i + 1;

    //without this 7th line I get a segmentation fault at line 15 (without line 15 program termines successfully)
    printf("%d %d %d\n\n", numofusers, numofmovies, curruser -> usercode);
    //through this line of code I understood that it does what I want it to do

    curruser -> next = calloc(1, sizeof(struct user * ));
    curruser = curruser -> next;
}
curruser = headuser;
//--------
printf("!%d!\n", numofmovies);
```

The first line of the file contains two integers, which are read with no issues, then I try to allocate some memory for the users.
If the first `printf` is there, no segmentation fault and everything works; otherwise it doesn't. I've already tried some potential solutions from this website but they didn't fix the issue. There must be somewhere I'm not aware of...

Comment: Can we see what `numofusers`, `numofmovies`, and `curruser` are?

Comment: In particular, how do you allocate the first `curruser`?

Comment: Run your code through valgrind.  If you're mismanaging memory it will tell you where.

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso `struct user* headuser=calloc(1, sizeof(struct user*));` and `struct user* curruser=headuser;` Answer to the first question is: `int numeroutenti, numerofilm_unici, numerofilm_nonunici;`

Comment: please put relevant code in your post.

Comment: `sizeof(struct user*)` is wrong, you want to allocate space for the thing being pointed to, which in this case is a `struct user`, change that to `struct user* headuser=calloc(1, sizeof(struct user));` or better yet `struct user* headuser=calloc(1, sizeof(*headuser));`

Comment: I feel so dumb!! thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're allocating the wrong amount of memory:

```
calloc(1, sizeof(struct user * ));
```

You are allocating enough memory for a pointer, not a whole object.

It should be

```
calloc(1, sizeof(struct user));
```

(And, there's no reason to use `calloc` here over `malloc`.)